# How to change position of a moving body - Box2D

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

I currently have a body created that is Dynamic and moves at a constant speed with a Vector2(). What I want is for when the body leaves the edge of the screen, to come back from that current point back to its original point instantaneously. How do I do this?

```
    a.applyForceToCenter(aMovement, true);
    a.applyTorque(3000, true);

    FixtureDef fDef = new FixtureDef();
    BodyDef ballD = new BodyDef();

    ballD.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;

    //random location for asteroid
    int aLoc = (int) (aLocation * 15);
    float x = 300;
    switch(aLoc)
    {
    case 0:
        ballD.position.set(x, -105);
        break;
    case 1:
        ballD.position.set(x, -95);
        break;
    case 2:
        ballD.position.set(x, -80);
        break;
    case 3:
        ballD.position.set(x, -65);
        break;
    case 4:
        ballD.position.set(x, -50);
        break;
    case 5:
        ballD.position.set(x, -35);
        break;
    case 6:
        ballD.position.set(x, -20);
        break;
    case 7:
        ballD.position.set(x, -5);
        break;
    case 8:
        ballD.position.set(x, 10);
        break;
    case 9:
        ballD.position.set(x, 25);
        break;
    case 10:
        ballD.position.set(x, 40);
        break;
    case 11:
        ballD.position.set(x, 55);
        break;
    case 12:
        ballD.position.set(x, 70);
        break;
    case 13:
        ballD.position.set(x, 85);
        break;
    default:
        ballD.position.set(x, 0);
    }

    PolygonShape asteroid = new PolygonShape();
    asteroid.setAsBox(12.5f, 12.5f);

    //asteroid definition
    fDef.shape = asteroid;
    fDef.density = .5f;
    fDef.friction = .25f;
    fDef.restitution = .75f;

    a = world.createBody(ballD);
    a.createFixture(fDef);
    a.setFixedRotation(false);

   //asteroid image
    aSprite = new Sprite(new Texture("img/asteroid-icon.png"));
    aSprite.setSize(12.5f * 4, 12.5f * 4);
    aSprite.setOrigin(aSprite.getWidth() / 2, aSprite.getHeight() / 2);
    a.setUserData(aSprite);
    asteroid.dispose();
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Body.setTransform()` for that task, but I would not do that. `setTransform()` causes a lot of trouble in the long run.

For me it lead to weird bugs. For example using `setTransform` disabled my `ContactFilter` in random moments, which cost me several days of debugging until I found that.

Furthermore it causes non-physical behaviour, because you basically teleport the `Body`.

Better would be to destroy the `Body` completely and recreate a new one at the same initial position of the old one.

Comment: How could I do that the way I want? What I want is for this to occur forever with the asteroid moving across the screen and then being put back in its original spot to move across again.

Comment: Don't forget to wake up the body if you use `setTransform`. It might be inactive and will therefore not be processed at the new position!

```java
body.setTransform(targetTeleportPosition, body.angle);
body.setAwake(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the position of your Box2D `a` body instantly through this method:

`a.setTransform(new_x, new_y, new_angle);`

With this, you can create a condition that sets the x and y position of the body back to its original position when the x or y value of the body is outside of the screen.

```
if(outsideBounds()){
    a.setTransform(start_x, start_y, start_angle);
}
```

You can check whether your object is offscreen by either checking its Box2D position and its converted screen coordinates, or by checking the sprite's location.

Once you've received the x and y screen positions, you can compare them to the screen bounds like this:

`pos_x>screenWidth||pos_x<0||pos_y>screenHeight||pos_y<0`

This can be improved by including the dimensions of the object, depending on when you want the transformation to happen:

```
(pos_x-objWidth)>screenWidth || (pos_x+objWidth)<0 ||
(pos_y-objHeight)>screenHeight || (pos_y+objHeight)<0
```

Comment: How do i get the position of the body?

Comment: You can get the position `Vector2` of the body through `a.getPosition()`. For more information on LibGDX/Box2D bodies, check out [this](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.html) link. As pointed out in noone's answer, using `setTransform` can cause problems, so use this method at your own risk, or to avoid problems, follow noone's suggestion and recreate the body.

Comment: Don't forget to wake up the body if you use `setTransform`. It might be inactive and will therefore not be processed at the new position!

```java
body.setTransform(targetTeleportPosition, body.angle);
body.setAwake(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```java
body.setTransform(newX, newY, newAngle);
body.setAwake(true);
```

Waking up the body is important.
It might be currently inactive and without waking it up neither gravity nor any immediate collisions will affect it at the new position.